# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in Qt: gui widgets printsupport macextras

Tags: qt, qt5, openscad

I'm trying to compile OpenSCAD on my Mac. When the build script reaches the line `qmake qscintilla.pro` it spits out the error `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: gui opengl concurrent widgets printsupport macextras` If I run `qmake` on its own I recieve more errors for missing modules `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: gui opengl concurrent widgets printsupport macextras` I added `QT += macextras` to my qt.pro file to see if it would stop complaining about macextras, but that didn't work either.

I looked inside `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1` and I can see `qtmacextras` but I don't see the other modules mentioned.

Any ideas how I could get these modules for Mac?

I thought that qt was being compiled by the following script

```
build_qt()
    {
      version=$1

      if [ -d $DEPLOYDIR/lib/QtCore.framework ]; then
        echo "qt already installed. not building"
        return
      fi

      echo "Building Qt" $version "..."
      cd $BASEDIR/src
      rm -rf qt-everywhere-opensource-src-$version
      if [ ! -f qt-everywhere-opensource-src-$version.tar.gz ]; then
         curl -O -L http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/4.8/4.8.5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5.tar.gz
      fi
      tar xzf qt-everywhere-opensource-src-$version.tar.gz
      cd qt-everywhere-opensource-src-$version
      patch -p0 < $OPENSCADDIR/patches/qt4/patch-src_corelib_global_qglobal.h.diff
      patch -p0 < $OPENSCADDIR/patches/qt4/patch-libtiff.diff
      patch -p0 < $OPENSCADDIR/patches/qt4/patch-src_plugins_bearer_corewlan_qcorewlanengine.mm.diff
      if $USING_CLANG; then
        # FIX for clang
        sed -i "" -e "s/::TabletProximityRec/TabletProximityRec/g"  src/gui/kernel/qt_cocoa_helpers_mac_p.h
        PLATFORM="-platform unsupported/macx-clang"
      fi
      if $OPTION_32BIT; then
        QT_32BIT="-arch x86"
      fi
      case "$OSX_VERSION" in
        9)
          # libtiff fails in the linker step with Mavericks / XCode 5.0.1
          MACOSX_RELEASE_OPTIONS=-no-libtiff
          # wlan support bails out with lots of compiler errors, disable it for the build
          patch_qt_disable_core_wlan "$version"
          ;;
        *)
          MACOSX_RELEASE_OPTIONS=
          ;;
      esac
      ./configure -prefix $DEPLOYDIR -release $QT_32BIT -arch x86_64 -opensource -confirm-license $PLATFORM -fast -no-qt3support -no-svg -no-phonon -no-audio-backend -no-multimedia -no-javascript-jit -no-script -no-scripttools -no-declarative -no-xmlpatterns -nomake demos -nomake examples -nomake docs -nomake translations -no-webkit $MACOSX_RELEASE_OPTIONS
      make -j"$NUMCPU" install
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling Qt from source or do you use the online installer? `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1` sounds like you have the Qt source code that you need to compile before you can use it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I added a smart part of the entire build script that seems responsible for building Qt.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using the macosx-build-dependencies.sh script. If you do, you need to set up your environment first, to search for libraries in the right places:

```
$ source setenv_mac-qt5.sh
```